# Constructors with objects as parameters

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

Suppose I have a class as follows:

```
class A{
    int x ; 
    A( int i ){
        x = i ; 
    }
}
```

And I have another class B which has an instance of class A as an member object.

```
class B{
    int y ; 
    A obj_a ; 
    B( int j , A a ){
        y = j ; 
        obj_a = a ; 
    }
}
```

When I do the following :

```
int main(){
        A obj1( 1 ) ; // obj.x has value 1
        B obj2( 2 , obj1 ) ; 
    }
```

The 2nd line throws an error saying no function call of the form A::A(). I know this means that a default style constructor is missing , but why do I need this ? obj1 is created using the defined constructor so that isn't an issue.

My current line of thought is that `A a` and `obj_a = a` would invoke the copy constructor which is implicitly defined.

Note: I have excluded private,public etc for brevity.

Comment: Post the actual error.  Your ctor is probably complaining that it should be `const int i`;

Comment: You explicitly asked for it by not using the initializer list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An object must be fully consistent, all of its members constructed, by the time it enters the body of the constructor. So in

```
B( int j , A a ){
    y = j ; 
    obj_a = a ; 
}
```

before

```
{
    y = j ; 
    obj_a = a ; 
}
```

gets a chance to do anything, `obj_a` must have been constructed.

Since no instruction on how to construct `obj_a` has been provided with the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), `obj_a` will be built with the default constructor for class `A`. Class `A` has no default constructor, no `A::A()`, so the error is raised.

The solution is to use the Member Initializer List instead of assignment inside the body of the function. Not only does this save you construction of an object that will promptly be over written, the compiler also has more lee-way to optimize and you may get some other small improvements.

Class `B` should be:

```
class B{
    int y ; 
    A obj_a ; 
    B( int j , A a ): y(j), obj_a(a)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: is the object `a` created by value here ? Is it possible to pass by reference ?

Comment: @AbhinavVishak `a` is currently passed by value and probably requires a copy. Yes you can pass `a` by reference.

Answer (score 3):

`obj_a = a` calls `operator=`, not the copy constructor. The thing is, `obj_a` is initialized using the default constructor, *because you haven't specified which constructor to call in the initializer list.*

```
B( int j , A a ) /*: obj_a{}*/ { /*...*/ }
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          implicit call to default constructor
```

You have to explictly call the constructor with one argument in the member initialization list:

```
B( int j , A a ) : obj_a{ a } { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Well the issue is not so much with `obj_a = a` . Its the `A a` inside the parameter list. How do I fix that ?

Comment: @AbhinavVishak `A a` is **not** the problem when it's in the parameter list. The problem is the lack of `obj_a` in the mem-initialiser list (the list following the `:`).

Comment: @agnew I did the changes you suggested, and it compiles. Thanks ! I'm still a bit confused about the use of initializer lists, wil do some reading on that. I assume that after using the ` : obj_a{a} ` , i wont need the `obj_a = a` ??